# How to remove duplicates from a query search elasticsearch

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch, duplicates

I am looking for the solution to remove duplicate from a search.

*The problem:*

I retreive article from google news and other rss feeds.It is possible to find the same article in the **same paper** with the **same title** and the **same content** that appears several times. But identified with different ID's
Sometimes we can even detect a flood from the newspaper. When I try a keyword I have the same result as that item come back a dozen times

Assume this exemple :

```
_index: actu
_type: page
_id: 4e3f3fc8-b535-399c-a176-ddbbf755ac82
_score: 2.0202384
_source: {
      feedname: my_news_paper
      title: some news 
      author: Bob smith
      description: Something happened in the world
      link: http://www.example.com/journal20140729/
      publishedDate: 2014-07-28T23:00:00.000Z
      source: null
      raw: { }
      categories: [
                   Journal
                  ]
      enclosures: [
      {
         url: http://www.example.com
         type: null
         length: 0
      }
      ]
  river: actu
 }
}
```

My query is something like that:

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
    {
      "fuzzy_like_this": {
        "fields": [
          "_all",
          "title^2",
          "description^4"
        ],
        "like_text": "my_key_word"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  }
```

Thanks